# Custom WebControls.DropDownList ViewState

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom web control that's just a simple DropDownList which is preloaded with all the states in the US. It's working for the most part, however after post back the control reverts to its initial state. (I am able to get the selected value in the post back). What will I need to implement in order for the list to retain it's selected item after post back?

Here's my control class:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:StateDropDownList runat=server></{0}:StateDropDownList>")]
public class StateDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    private void Populatedropdown()
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        this.Items.Add(new ListItem("Alabama", "AL"));
        /* the rest .... */
        this.Items.Add(new ListItem("Wyoming", "WY"));

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        Populatedropdown();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is not an issue with the control being rebound from a datasource. The goal of this custom control is to avoid the need to constantly bind drop down lists from a state table. The problem I'm trying to resolve is how do I maintain the selected value of this custom dropdown on postback?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Populatedropdown()
{
    if(this.Items.Count == 0)
    {
      this.Items.Clear();
      this.Items.Add(new ListItem("Alabama", "AL"));
      /* the rest .... */
      this.Items.Add(new ListItem("Wyoming", "WY"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `ListItems` to late in the [control life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Move your `Populatedropdown` call into the OnInit method and your problem should go away.

Answer (score -1):

Are you doing this?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //only bind the control when the page is first loaded
            myControl.DataBind();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a "static" dropdownlist which you can drop from the tool box into the webForm which already contains the states. The list isn't bound to any datasource, the list items are added in the controls class.